# How to wrap text in a cell in a datatable?

Tags: css, primereact

I've got variable length text being displayed in a column within a [PrimeReact DataTable](https://primereact.org/datatable/). In my experimentation, the following:

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

td{
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

causes the  table to scroll horizontally, while the following:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

tr{
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

td{
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

causes the text to be cut off if it goes too long. How can I get the text to wrap and grow in height? Barring that, how can I detect if it's too long so I can throw in an ellipsis […] and hover-text with the full text?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks, @Paulie_D. It turns out that the further exploration required to build a snippet revealed it was a css problem that was easily fixed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was css that was applying `text-wrap: nowrap` for some reason. I applied `wrap` to that cell and all is now good in the world.